Help decoding weird Id current behavior at high motor speeds!
I have implemented a motor controller which employs FOC to control the speed of a PMSM motor, similar to this:

Normally Id reference (IDref) is set to 0 and only the Iq reference (IQref) (quadrature current reference) is modified to apply the desired torque.
Up until a speed of 10 kRPM, the Id feedback is close to 0. No problems here.
But as I start to increase the motor speed (Wref) to a value above 10 kRPM, I notice that Id feedback starts to increase and at one point, as I keep increasing the motor speed, the whole system becomes unstable.
Note that the same behavior is observed at no load and loaded conditions.
Also note that the vector sum of Vdref and Vqref has to be less than 1, so keeping this in mind, I Limit Vdref to +-0.30 and Vqref to +-0.91.
The motor's back EMF constant Ke is 18 V per 1000 RPM and input DC is 300 V.
Unfortunately I don't have the motor datasheet to know the exact motor characteristics apart from what I can measure.
Why does the Id feedback (IDFbk) start to increase?
At first I thought maybe the input DC is not enough but at 10000 RPM the back EMF is only 180 V?
Am I missing something here?
Could you please give me possible conditions why this can happen? (By "this", I mean increase in Id feedback current (IDFbk), whenever the motor speed is above 10 kRPM)
Does this also mean that to attain higher speeds above 10000 RPM, IDref (IDref) can no longer be zero (field weakening),
Please correct me if I am wrong but shouldn't field weakening be applied only if there is not enough input DC (back EMF > input DC)?
Many thanks for your help!

How similar to "this"? The devil will be in the detail.

@Andy aka, i don't follow, by "this" i mean increase in Id feedback current as the speed increased to a value above 10k RPM.

I have implemented a motor controller which employs FOC to control the speed of a PMSM motor, similar to this: <-- similar to this

oh! I was referring to the image which I have posted, which has all the acronyms present to explain the problems(Vdref, Vqref...etc)

So, the diagram is representative of what you are trying to do? I'm not trying to be critical; I'm just trying to establish what information in the diagram is valid and, what isn't.

Yes, Correct. Its a diagram of the FOC control that I have currently implemented. I tried highlighting all the important components incase some additional information that may be required to get a viable solution to my problem.

Is the motor drive voltage and motor fully balanced above 10,000 rpm. I can't really help much other than make the odd silly suggestion.

yes, the motor is balanced >10 K RPM, I tested the same motor using a cheap off the shelf motor driver and it works up to 15K RPM without any problems.

Is that driven from the same 3 phase inverter?

yes , the motor is driven from the same inverter
